# GLSL - perspective correction for stereo view

Tags: opengl, glsl, perspective

I'm trying to fix the perspective in GLSL from **incorrect**

[image: Incorrect]

to **correct**

[image: Correct]

In VS I added:

```
float gradient = 0.5;
mat4 transformGeometry = mat4(1.0, 0.0, gradient, 0.0,
                              0.0, 1.0, 0.0,      0.0,
                              0.0, 0.0, 1.0,      0.0,
                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0,      1.0);
gl_Position = mvp_matrix * transformGeometry * a_position;
```

I think the result looks ok

[image: Result]

BUT after rotating 90 degree right, it doesn't look like as I expected.

[image: Rot90r]

After next rotation 90 degree down, it looks even worse.

[image: Rot90d]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved - it should be

```
projectionMatrix * transformGeometry * modelView
```

instead of the

```
MVP * transformGeometry
```